# how to replace markdown tags into html by python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace some "markdown" tags into html tags.

for example:

```
#Title1#
##title2##
Welcome to **My Home Page**
```

will be turned into

```
<h1>Title1</h1>
<h2>title2</h2>
Welcome to <b>My Home Page</b>
```

I just don't know how to do that...For **Title1**,I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
text = '''
        #Title1#
        ##title2##
'''
 p = re.compile('^#\w*#\n$')
 print(p.sub('<h1>\w*</h1>',text))
```

but nothing happens..

```
 #Title1#
 ##title2##
```

How could those bbcode/markdown language come into html tags?

Comment: You should use a [markdown parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown)

Comment: Look for some Markdown parser. A search for `pypi markdown parser` gives several results. I don't have any experience with them, so I think you should download them and try them out on some Markdown formatted text.

Comment: Thanks, But I want to know how those markdown languages works and I am willing to write my own style markdown standards for my homepage with python3 cgi program.

Comment: for this reason I never solve the problem with markdown packages..

Comment: @BingSun: The actual parsing algorithm is described in CommonMark specs in details, if I remember correctly - it's a two-pass algorithm - first pass to identify block constructs, and 2nd pass to parser the rest. If you want to learn to write a parser, the best way is to look at how existing parsers are written.

Comment: Thank you @nhahtdh, I will try to learn markdown parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this regex: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN3jU0/1)

Here you can see how I substituted the `#...#` into `<h1>...</h1>`.
I believe you can get this to work with double `#` and so on to get other markdown features considered, but still you should listen to @Thomas and @nhahtdh comments and use a markdown parser. Using regexes in such cases is unreliable, slow and unsafe.

As for inline text like `**...**` to `<b>...</b>` you can try this regex with substitution: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW0hR1/2). Hope you can twink this for other features like underlining and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I will try markdown parser later. I tried to reset text='#title#' and print(p.sub('<h1>\1</h1>',text)). the program returns <h1></h1>. what does \1 means? how to define contents that never need to be modified?

Comment: `\1` is a backreference to capture group 1. You will need to check how to do this in Python, as I am not familiar with this language.

Comment: @BingSun I added regex for `**...**` part, you might want to check this out too.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very kind of you!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression does not work because in the default mode, `^` and `$` (respectively) matches the beginning and the end of the whole string.

> `'^'`
>
> (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, *and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline* (my emph.)
>
> `'$'`
>
> Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in `MULTILINE` mode also matches before a newline. `foo` matches both ‘foo’ and ‘foobar’, while the regular expression `foo$` matches only ‘foo’. More interestingly, searching for `foo.$` in `'foo1\nfoo2\n'` matches ‘foo2’ normally, but ‘foo1’ in `MULTILINE` mode; searching for a single `$` in `'foo\n'` will find two (empty) matches: one just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.
>
> ([7.2.1. Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax))

Add the flag `re.MULTILINE` in your compile line:

```
p = re.compile('^#(\w*)#\n$', re.MULTILINE)
```

and it should work – at least for single words, such as your example. A better check would be

```
p = re.compile('^#([^#]*)#\n$', re.MULTILINE)
```

– any sequence that does not contain a `#`.

In both expressions, you need to add parentheses around the part you want to copy so you can use that text in your replacement code. See the official documentation on [Grouping](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) for that.

Comment: When you mention "single line mode", it's going to be confused with `s` flag which makes `.` matches new line. (Well, the naming is quite confusing, and I was bitten by it when I started out). It's more accurate to say, by default `^` and `$` matches the beginning and the end of the whole string. You need MULTILINE mode (m flag) to make them also match the beginning and the end of the line.